# After reactoring packages in Netbeans, I can't commit anymore

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

After refactoring some packages/classes, when i try to commit my project i get this error:

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Item 'One-of-my-project's-package' is out of date
svn: DELETE of '/svn/Repository/!svn/wrk/fe1d333f-3901-0010-acd1-d750d86b0019/One-of-my-project's-package': 409 Conflict (https://mysvnrepositoryserver.com)

The SVN command returned with an error which indicates that some files in your working copy are out of date.
Run update and attempt your command again.

How i can fix it? Running "update" won't overwrite my classes, deleting all the latest modifications?

Comment: Consider backing up your data some other way, perhaps by creating a Jar file, then yes, run an update. After doing that, if your data is still in place, repeat your attempt to run a commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened many times to me, it is very frustrating. Updating won't disturb anything if nobody else has committed in the meantime, and even if there were other commits, only a regular update will happen that will merge the changes into your files (or, in case of a conflict, generate the usual commit markings). However, the update may not help, either. What is usually at hand is a "tree conflict", which doesn't concern any specific file, but directory info. You probably renamed a package, that renamed a directory and created your situation.

Try updating and, if it doesn't help, you probably will have to make a backup and manually revert parts of the working tree, then reapply your changed files.

Comment: I'm the only developer working on this project, so there aren't "other user's commits" issues.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand my words: other users are not causing this.